# Как применить text-transform там, где нельзя? :visited, text-transform, CSS

Tags: html, css, текст, transform

Вот мой код:

```css
.mainNav ul li a {
  color: black;
  font-weight: 501;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.mainNav ul li a:hover {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.mainNav ul li a:visited {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<nav class="mainNav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="part.html">Participate</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

...который конечно же не работает, да-да. Короче, по моим размышлениям при посещении любой ссылки (в моем случае это `Home`, так как я еще не создал `part.html`), текст должен меняться с обычного на заглавные буквы. Но этого не происходит. Подскажите, что делаю не так? Если что, `:hover` работает спокойно.

Comment: Для visited можно изменять только цвета, все остальные стили специально не работают

Comment: А можно как-то сделать, чтобы-таки изменить регистр?

Comment: Как я уже написал в первом комментарии - нельзя

Comment: @andreymal, цвета, тоже не очень применяются, похоже :)

Comment: Ладно, спасибо. Можешь написать это в ответы, я его приму @andreymal

Comment: в принципе можно при клике менять регистр, но это уже js + как бы если ты кликнул, то посетил сайт, нет?

Answer (score 1):

1. Visited должен стоять до тэга hover
2. Только color принимается от сss. [Вот](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/v/visited/)
3. Как поменять не только цвет :visited, но и другие свойства? Можем использовать (оч. плохо) JS, пример вот - [код-баян](https://jsfiddle.net/chil7/wfoqnygz/2/)

P.S. 3й пункт это костыль с помощью jquery. Идея: :visited можно официально поменять только цвет, меняем цвет и проверяем с помощью js, если да то добавляем класс.

```
    $(function(){
  $("a").each(function(index, link){
    var $link = $(link);
    console.log($link.css("color"));
    //проверяем, это синий цвет ссылки, если да то добавляем класс.
    if($link.css("color") == "rgb(0, 0, 238)"){
      $link.addClass("visited");
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Этот скрипт не работает. Во-первых, 0,0,238 — это не розовый, а ярко-синий, а во-вторых, даже на розовых ссылках скрипт видит только синий цвет, и таким образом класс visited будет добавлен на ВСЕ ссылки независимо от их посещения

Comment: Да, с цветом ошибся, но это костыль. Можно проверить, в каком div стоит этот блок и добавлять только туда, куда нужно.

Comment: Сделать скрипт работающим невозможно в любом случае. Это специальное ограничение в браузерах. «Код-баян» по ссылке тоже не работает.